# Incremental backup with crontab

Tags: backup, cron, rsync, nas

I have a NAS on my LAN and I want to have an incremental backup once a day on a removable hard disk and then a full backup once a week. I heard about `crontab` and `rsync`, but I don't have any idea on how to do incremental and full backups.

My PC is running Linux, so I can use `rsync` and `crontab`. How should I set up `rsync` and `crontab` working together to have a daily incremental backup and a weekly full backup?

Supposing that `NAS IP Address: 192.168.1.100` and the removable hard disk is plugged in my PC with USB, what scripts do I have to write? I need to backup all the folders in the NAS.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a detailed instruction about how to use rsync and crontab to backup linux files.
http://www.cubebackup.com/blog/automatic-backup-linux-using-rsync-crontab/

But you need to understand the process and made modifications based on your need.

Comment: It would be good if you could include the salient points from your link, in case the link dies some time in the future...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the answers and hints. I've found a way to do what I asked for and I want to share it with all of you.

1. **First:** *backup.sh*. In this file we set up the source directory and the destination folder in which all the files we'll be copied. The code is easy to read.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   #Backup script

   #Config
   src="/Users/user/Backup/from/*"
   dest="/Users/user/Backup/to"
   log="/Users/user/Backup/backup.log"
   user=$USER
   date=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y %T")

   #Output on log file
   echo "--- Start Backup" >> $log
   echo "--- Source: $src" >> $log
   echo "--- Dest  : $dest" >> $log
   echo "--- $date by $user" >> $log
   echo "---" >> $log

   #Command
   rsync -t -r -v --progress --stats --delete $src $dest >> $log

   #Output on log file
   echo "---" >> $log
   echo "--- End Backup" >> $log
   ```
2. **Second:** *crontab*. With a few command lines we can setting up a crontab job every day (night) at 23.59. Open the terminal (with root privileges `$ su` and enter root's password. If you are using root for the first time, first set the password for it with `$ sudo passwd`).
   Open the crontab editor with

   ```
   # crontab -e
   ```

   Then make the previous script (supposed to be saved in `/Users/user/Backup/backup.sh`) runnable everyday at 23:59.

   ```
   59 23 * * * /Users/user/Backup/backup.sh
   ```

Comment: this is not doing an incremental backup. this is only sync'ing your `$src` and `$dest` once a day. It is "incremental" in the sense that rsync will only copy the  updated/added files and won't copy everything again. But that's not an [incremental backup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_backup) which would keep each daily backup so you could choose to restore to last friday's or last thursday's backup. Your setup only allows you restoring yesterday's backup.